# Is there a way to implement infinite scrolling in a way that works with the back button?

Tags: html, jquery

Clicking on an item in a site that uses infinite scrolling is incredibly frustrating because I cannot easily return to my place on the page by clicking the back button.  I end up spending several minutes getting back to my original spot.  Why is it so difficult to place me back on the page where I left off?

Comment: yes there is. but until we know what you did try we dont have an answer.

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I haven't been able to find any decent information on the subject.